# MinHash single vs multiple hash functions

Tags: probability, algorithms, hash-function

I'm trying to get familiar with MinHash function, and there are a few things a do not understand:

1. *Why to use multiple hash function version over single hash function alternative?* [MinHash wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash) says - both implementations of MinHash gives the same expected error. But in the same time single hash function is cheaper.
2. *Which hash functions I have to use in both versions of MinHash?* Is it acceptable to use "cheaper" hash functions in multi-hash-function version?
3. *Are there any ways to tune accuracy/speed besides increasing amount of hash functions?*